# why out_channels must be greater then channel_multiplier * in_channels in pointwise_filter which is the parameter of tf.nn.separable_conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow

Please see the code first :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
input_data = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(10,9,9,3), dtype=np.float32)
#depthwise_filter (filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, channel_multiplier)
depthwise_filter = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(2,2,3,5), dtype=np.float32)
#pointwise_filter (1, 1, channel_multiplier * in_channels, out_channels)
pointwise_filter = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1,1,15,8), dtype=np.float32)
y = tf.nn.separable_conv2d(input_data, depthwise_filter, pointwise_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
print(tf.shape(y))
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tsfl.py", line 36, in <module>
    y = tf.nn.separable_conv2d(input_data, depthwise_filter, pointwise_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py", line 486, in separable_conv2d
    channel_multiplier * in_channels, out_channels))
ValueError: Refusing to perform an overparameterized separable convolution: channel_multiplier * in_channels = 5 * 3 = 15 > 8 = out_channels
```

When channel_multiplier * in_channels <= out_channels, it works.

why out_channels must be greater then channel_multiplier * in_channels?

Answer (score 0):

This constraint has been removed in current Tensorflow master branch. See [Tensorflow: What does tf.nn.separable_conv2d do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092037/tensorflow-what-does-tf-nn-separable-conv2d-do) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from `Tensorflow` version, I've upgraded tf from `1.1.0` to `1.10.0` and it worked.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.10.0
```